# Interface<T> with T as return type from extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, extension-methods

Maybe I am stuck in my point of view for this issue. I just want to eliminate need for cast (MyClass).

```
var c = (MyClass)new MyClass { }.MyExtensionMethod();
```

MyClass implements IMyInferface

IMyInterface.cs

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
        where T : class
{
    // props
}
```

MyIntefaceExtenstions.cs

```
public static class MyInterfaceExtensions
{
    public static T MyExtensionMethod<T>(this IMyInterface<T> item, Guid id)
    {
         item.CreatedTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
         item.MySecondExtMethod(id);
         return (T)item;
    }
}
```

And I still get error "The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter" on `this IMyInterface<T> item`.

Comment: What is the relationship between `ITrackable<T>` and `IMyInteface<T>`?

Comment: You have to add `where T: class` to your extension method as well. That is, if you're talking about the same interface. Your examples are showing different interfaces though, was that an oversight or intentional?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I edited it. Missed this one.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen missed that one. Yes it's same.

Comment: Generic constraints need to be satisfied where other generic types are used. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

@LasseV.Karlsen answered it in comment.
I missed `where T : class` for methods.

```
public static T MyExtensionMethod<T>(this IMyInterface<T> item, Guid id)
     where T : class
{
   // code
}
```